# jQuery dataTables won't send POST array

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post, datatables

I have a DataTable that won't pass the data parameter via the POST array.  The example from the library documentation (https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.data) would seem to indicate that this syntax is correct but a print_r of the $_POST array in the PHP file called indicates that the POST array is empty.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var mydatatable = $("#mydatatablediv").DataTable(
{
    "ajax":{
        "url": "path-to-server/backendfile.php",
        "contentType": "application/json",
        "type": "POST",
        "data": {"myeventid":"5"} //replaced with variable in production
    }, //end ajax parameter
    "columns": [
        {"data":"field1","width":"30%"},
        {"data":"field2","width":"20%"},            
        {"data":"field3","width":"5%"},
        {"data":"field4","width":"30%"},
        {"data":"field5","width":"5%"}
    ],
    "paging":false,
    "info":false
});//end dataTable
});//end DOM load
```

Comment: is the javascript file correctly included in the html file with <script> tag?, does the "mydatatablediv" exist in the html? is the datatable library   correctly included with <script> tag on the html?, can you see the ajax request firing on the browser's developer tools?

Answer (score 2):

Removing the "contentType": "application/json" parameter resolved the issue.  I had added this parameter per the DataTables website documentation at https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.data under the 'Submit data as JSON in the request body' section.  But as stated, this is not necessary.